# Почему из статического контекста нельзя обратиться к нестатическому полю, если оно находится в этом же классе, но можно, если оно находися в другом?

Tags: java

Пример:

```
public class Counter {
   private int count;

   public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(count); //compile time error
   }
}
```

Пример 2:

```
public class Counter {
    public int count = 0;
}    

public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        System.out.println(c.count); //OK
    }
}
```

Comment: А вам не кажется, что примеры не равнозначны? Почему в первом случае не `Counter c = new Counter();  System.out.println(c.count);`, который, между прочим, будет прекрасно работать?

Comment: думаю будет полезно - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @pavlofff правильно сказал - при вызове статической функции в классе сам класс не создаётся. Вы можете получить доступ или к статическим значениям классов, или к переменным, созданным внутри статической функции как в вашем примере.

Answer (score 7):

В пределах одного класса нестатические переменные не существуют без создания экземпляра класса и их нельзя использовать в статических методах напрямую.

Во втором случае вы создаете экземпляр класса и в статическом методе используете значение переменной этого экземпляра.

Такая конструкция (равноценная первому варианту) так же не будет компилироваться:

```
public class Counter {
    public int count = 0;
}    

public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Counter.count); //NOT OK
    }
}
```